# Родители и потомки

Tags: java

```
package credit;
public class Credit {
    String Surname;
    String Name;
    public void register(String S,String N)
    {
        Surname = S;
        Name    = N;
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Фамилия "+Name);
        System.out.println("Имя "+Surname);
    }
}
// Это Родитель,здесь нету ошибок

package credit2;
public class Credit1 extends **Credit** {
    int Summa;
    public void register(String S,String N,int sum)
           {
       **super.reigster(S,N);**
       Summa = sum;
   }
    public void show()
   {
       **super.show();**
       System.out.println(Summa);
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        **Credit** t1  = new **Credit**();
        **Credit** t2 = new **Credit**();
        Credit1 t3 = new Credit1();
        t1.register("Ivanov","Vasya");
        t2.register("Kozlov","Dima");
        t3.register("Luchin","Mark");
        t1.show();
        t2.show();
        t3.show();
    }
}
```

Это потомок, что я подчеркнул жирным. Там выдаёт ошибки.

Comment: а что за IDE? Eclipse бы тебя поправил... в общем блокнот только не поправил бы

Comment: там рядом нет никого кто б вас по руках бил, за название переменных начинающихся с заглавной?

Answer (score 2):

В пакете credit2 впишите:

```
package credit2;
import credit.Credit;
//дальше как обычно
```

**update**

не `super.reigster(S,N);`, а `super.register(S,N);`

*P.S. Ну и программеры пошли, не умеют даже трактовать ошибки показанные IDE... Куда страна катится? Перфокарт на вас нет!*

Comment: перфокарты?))да школьники уже не знают что такое 3.5"... =) да и это конечно холивар =), но "ребята, решают проблемы", даже если объяснения сводятся к "кнопочки тык-тык-тык, буковка красная стала, куда нажать, что бы было все хорошо?" =)

Comment: Выдает ошибку "package credit does not exist",я понял если перевести на РУ то переводится такой папки не существует.P.S. IDE показывает только cannot find symbol,и всё.

Comment: Млин - так ты проверь лежит в каталоге credit файлик Credit.java?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка: super.reigster(S,N)-super.register(S,N). И вроде-бы всё...по крайне мере у меня работает... хотя сам пример не совсем понятен(смысл)...

Comment: P.S. Извините конечно-же еще "import"

Comment: Выдает ошибку "package credit does not exist",я понял если перевести на РУ то переводится такой папки не существует.

Comment: удали эти пакеты нафиг =) заново сделай их импорт, скинь классы в один пакет

Comment: plz Скиньте реализацию на NetBeansе, и так и сяк кручу,ВСЁ РАВНО ЧТО-ТО НЕ ТО ((((

Comment: @Alibek - ну не твое это походу. Ну его иди грузить помидоры на базаре - это же проще. А если не хочешь грузить помидоры - прочти для начала простенький учебник!

Comment: ыыыыы, вот так незатейливо, одним прогером становится --, а грузчиком ++ =)

Answer (score 0):

В NetBeans все работает нормально. Ошибка, как и было ранее замечено, в строке:

> super.reigster(S,N);

Сделай классы в одном пакете.
Я бы ещё сделал аннотацию к методу:
public void show() в классе Credit1, т.к. ты его переопределяешь :) И ещё одна ошибка: нужно поменять местами Name и Surname в методе show().

Comment: Ой блен это мелкая ошибка , я её исправил,Зачем так дотошно быть правильным, настойчивость никто не отменял))) чтобы придумать лампочку было приведено 1000 неправильных методов и 1 из них был правильным...научусь,потом еще покажу я вам свои труды!!!а вашему уму каждый позавидует SuperHuman(в переводе СуперЧеловек)

Comment: Правильно, @Alibek, ваяйте. Главное побольше и самых важных задач. 

Просто потом, разговор с заказчиком, по поводу исправления супер-программ будет начинаться с 6 нулей (лучше бакинских).

Comment: @Alibek ну раз ответ @SuperHuman понравился поставь ему + и прими его ответ - так станешь еще ближе к касте прогеров :)

Comment: @Alibek, спасибо :)
Это не дотошность, а всего лишь внимание к мелочам, которые в твоем коде привели к ошибкам :) В свое время, и я таким болел, но исправился и теперь мне легче :)
Правильно подметил про Эдисона, будь настойчивее и у тебя все получится :)